# Passing variables through the URL in Laravel

Tags: variables, laravel, laravel-routing

I am very new to Laravel and I am trying to fully understand how routes work. I want to pass variables through the URL. I understood how I do that, but my problem is a little different:

routes.php

```
Route::get("/user/{user}", array(
    'as' => 'profile-user',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@user'
    ));
```

ProfileController.php

class ProfileController extends BaseController{

```
public function user($user) {
    $user = User::where('username', '=', Session::get('theuser') );


    if($user->count()) {
        $user = $user->first();

        return View::make('layout.profile')
        ->with('user', $user);

    }

    return App::abort(404);
}


}
```

In my View, simply:

```
{{ $user->username }}
```

Now my problem: This works somewhat, but after the press of a button, this URL will look something like this:

```
 [this is not a link](http://localhost/tutorial/public/index.php/user/%7Buser%7D)
```

If I get to edit the URL to something like

```
 [this is not a link](http://localhost/tutorial/public/index.php/user/Serban)
```

it does the same thing. But I do not wish to manually edit the URL. How can I get the second URL line without editing?

Answer (score 2):

When you are building your form, pass the `user` argument like this

```
Form::open(array('route' => array('route-name-for-update', $user->username)))
```

You may also use Form [Model Binding](http://laravel.com/docs/html#form-model-binding) (read more on the doc):

```
Form::model($user, array('route' => array('user.update', $user->username)))
```

Here, `user.update` is the route name that requires a route defined with this name for update method.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, a more interesting approach for me is to do something like this:

```
  Route::group(array('prefix' => 'user/{user}'), function()
    {

        Route::get("/{char}", array(
            'as' => 'profile-user',
            'uses' => 'ProfileController@user'));
    }   
    );
```

Controller:

```
 public function user($user, $char) {
    $user = User::where('username', '=', Session::get('theuser') );
    $char = Character::where('char_name', '=', 'Cucu' );

    if($user->count()) {
        $user = $user->first();
        $char = $char->first();

        return View::make('layout.profile')
        ->with('user', $user)
        ->with('char', $char);

    }

    return App::abort(404);
}
```

It doesn't seem for me to be able to do something like this at the push of a button

```
$logged_user = Session::get('theuser');
return Redirect::route('profile-user', $logged_user);
```

because I can't put 2 parameters in the Redirect function. This code will get the URL

```
  [this is not a link](http://localhost/tutorial/public/index.php/user/SerbanSpire)
```

which obviously doesn't exist
The correct URL would be

```
  [this is not a link]http://localhost/CaughtMiddle/tutorial/public/index.php/user/SerbanSpire/Cucu)
```

where SerbanSpire is the $user and Cucu is $char. How can I get the correct URL?

Answer (score 0):

When you link to a route you will need to pass the param to the route like so

`{{ route('profile-user', 'Serban') }}`